# Facebook/Twitter oauth on mobile ios / android , How to protect my App_id and secret on the app side?

Tags: ios, security, mobile, oauth, access-token

In order to initiate oauth on the mobile, I have to provide the application keys, which are very sensitive and must not be revealed, How do I protect them?
It's possible to hardcode it in the app, or to acquire it every time they are needed using a web service call, in any case, it looks like it is not well protected. Any suggestions?

Comment: save a App_id in seperate plist file, when ever you you read from plist file

Comment: use static library. Store it in a .m . generate .a file and use .h and get value of app id.

Comment: Is it common to do Server side oauth inside a browser component in the app? that will make it mych more secured

Comment: Do not store the app_id in a plist file! Anyone with access to the file system can easily read it.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to initiate oauth on the mobile, I have to provide the application keys.

You don't, you can use TWRequest (iOS 5) or [SLRequest](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-slrequest) (iOS 6+) to perform OAuth requests.

If, for some reason, you want to use your own consumer keys (in order to access direct messages for instance) then you can implement the [reverse auth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) flow.

You keep your consumer secret on your own server. Your server will request some tokens that will then be retrieved from your app and sent again through TWRequest / SLRequest. The response will be tokens valid for the user and *your app*, and you will be able to access the user's account from your server.

You can implement reverse auth by yourself or use the [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter#reverse-authentication) library to do so.

I don't know if the following scheme is enlightening or not but it can help.

[image]